# SendKeys taking to much time to enter text in Android App Automation Using TestNG,AVD Simulator,Appium Server

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

Here In my case , to enter text in `Text Field` I am using `driver.clear` to clear `Text Field` and then `driver.sendKeys` to enter text in `Text Field`.

But its taking too much time for `WebDriver(Selenium)` and `Appium Server` with real device and Android Virtual Device also.

Comment: Use genymotion as android emulator. As default emulator is very slow.

Comment: Cast to MobileElements and use setValue(String) method. A discussion to it can be seen [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/89) and reference to [java-client api](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.html#setValue%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @HelpingHands  I've been using real device ..... It is slow on that also.... Please help.... Or let me if there is any alternative method to search to enter text into text field.

Comment: If getting same issue in real device then it is your app. OR web service response issue. Not a selenium issue.

Comment: Have you used setValue instead of sendKeys......??... Please let me know if you did....

Answer (score 0):

You can download [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?ref=driverlayer.com#!/), and here's a [installation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjHk1VtLk8c).

I'm working with it and it's very fast.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Have you used setValue instead of sendKeys......??... Please let me know if you did....

Answer (score -1):

Try waiting for the element before sending it. Use this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
            .className("...............")));
```

Comment: Have you used setValue instead of sendKeys......??... Please let me know if you did....